# Rank of a block matric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to determine the rank of the matrix $M$ where :

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \end{bmatrix} $$

with $\mathbf{A} \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. Here is my try :

Using row operations on block matrices, we have :

$$ \mathrm{rank}(M) = \mathrm{rank}\Bigg( \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \end{bmatrix} \Bigg) = \mathrm{rank}\big( \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \end{bmatrix} \big). $$

Where $\displaystyle n \geq \mathrm{rg} \big( \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \end{bmatrix} \big) \geq \mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{A})$. I don't think if more can be said about the rank of the matrix $M$.

Comment: The rank is at most $\min\{n, \mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B)\}$ and at least $\min\{\mathrm{rank} A,\mathrm{rank} B\}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek : You're right, it is at least $\min(\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B))$ but how could it be at most $\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B)$ ? The $2n$ columns of $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \end{bmatrix}$ cannot be linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I still believe the rank is at most $n$.

Comment: The sum of the ranks might be $\leq n$. (More generally, the number you are interested in is exactly the sum of the ranks minus the dimension of the intersection of the column spaces of $A$ and $B$)

Comment: Yes, you're right!